# How can I expand an Array in a Dataframe in Scala/Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-xml

I used Databricks spark-xml package to read a XML file into Spark. The file hast the following datastructure:

```
<lib>
 <element>
  <genre>Thriller</genre>
  <dates>
   <date>2000-10-01</date>
   <date>2020-10-01</date>
  </dates>
 </element>
 <element>
  <genre>SciFi</genre>
  <dates>
   <date>2015-10-01</date>
  </dates>
 </element>
</lib>
```

After I load the data i get a dataframe that looks like:

```
root
 |-- genre: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publish_dates: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- publish_date: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

And "show" produces the following result:

```
gerne | dates
Th... | [WrappedArray(20...
```

Is it possible to get this result in the form:

```
gerne | date
Th... | 2000-...
Th... | 2020-...
Sci.. | 2015-...
```

I already tried:

```
val rdd = df.select("genre", "dates").rdd.map(row => (row(0), row(1))).flatMapValues(_.toString)
```

and

```
val rdd = df.select("genre", "dates").rdd.map(row => (row(0), Array(row(1)).toList)).flatMap {
  case (label, list) => {
    list.map( (_, label))
  }
}
```

and

```
val rdd = df.select("genre", "dates").withColumn("genre", explode($"dates"))
```

But nothing gets me the correct result, in fact the last version does not work at all, but i fould it via google.

Any help or tipps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You mentioned your `schema` to be

```
root
 |-- genre: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publish_dates: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- publish_date: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Which suggest that your `dataframe` to be

```
+--------+--------------------------------------+
|genre   |publish_dates                         |
+--------+--------------------------------------+
|thriller|[WrappedArray(2000-10-01, 2020-10-01)]|
+--------+--------------------------------------+
```

If this is the case then following `explode` function should give you the desired output

```
val finaldf = df.select("genre", "publish_dates").withColumn("publish_dates", explode(col("publish_dates.publish_date")))
finaldf.show(false)
```

Whose output is

```
+--------+-------------+
|genre   |publish_dates|
+--------+-------------+
|thriller|2000-10-01   |
|thriller|2020-10-01   |
+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: Many thanks. This works fine.

Comment: @JanusJato, great to hear that the answer helped :) you can help me too by accepting it. :) and an upvote when you are eligible